# R is the relation defined on the set of integers by xRy when ⌊x/2⌋ = ⌊y/2⌋. Prove that R is an equivalence relation and find the equivalence classes.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

So just to go through this real quick the Relation $R$ is an equivalence relation because it is

Reflexive - Yes, because for all $x$,  $⌊x/2⌋ = ⌊x/2⌋$, so $xRx$.

Symmetric - Yes, because for all $x$ and $y$ if  $⌊x/2⌋ = ⌊y/2⌋$, then $⌊y/2⌋ = ⌊x/2⌋$.

Transitive - Yes, because for all $x$ and $y$ if  $⌊x/2⌋ = ⌊y/2⌋$,  $xRy$, and  $⌊x/2⌋ = ⌊z/2⌋$ then  $xRz$ so  $⌊z/2⌋ = ⌊y/2⌋$ so $zRy$.

Since all 3 of these hold true it is an equivalence relation, now I get confused when it comes to defining an equivalence class.

Now I think for this to hold true

$(x +.5) > y > x$

I'm not sure how to put that into terms of an equivalence class, maybe like so?

$[x]_R =$ {$y|(x +.5) > y > x$}

or maybe

$[x,y]_R =$ {$y|(x,y) \in R$}

Comment: Maybe it would help to find the equivalence classes of the relation $xRy$ iff $\lfloor x \rfloor=\lfloor y\rfloor$ first?

Comment: I'm not sure how the definition of an equivalence class works in general. I"m just confused in how to read the notation. Do you mind explaining that, and I can give it a try?

Comment: Suppose that we're looking at the equivalence relation $xRy$ iff $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$ on the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers. The set $\mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into a bunch of disjoint pieces $E_j$ (these are the equivalence classes), such that for every pair of numbers $x,y \in E_j$, $xRy$. In other words, every number in an equivalence class is equivalent to every other number in it. Now, in this case, for a pair of real numbers $x$ and $y$, we have $xRy$ if and only if $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor = n$ for some integer $n$. So by inspection, (con't)

Comment: (con't) the equivalence classes are in bijection (one-to-one correspondence) with the integers. For every integer $n$, there is a corresponding class $E_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | \lfloor x \rfloor = n\}$. For example, $3$ and $3.2$ and $3.9$ are all in the same equivalence class because their floor is equal to 3, and we can write $[3]_R = [3.2]_R = [3.9]_R$, but for instance $7.1$ is not in the same equivalence class as the other three, so $[3]_R \neq [7.1]_R$.

Comment: Alright so for the equivalence class of $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$, for the relation to hold true, y must be less than  $\lfloor x \rfloor  +1$ and greater than  $\lfloor x \rfloor $, I think. I'm still not sure how to put into terms like  this [x]R= {y|(x+.5)>y>x}

Comment: You're not really thinking about it the right way. Instead of a pair $(x,y)$ with $x$ fixed, you should be thinking about which real numbers are equivalent to which other real numbers... For the equivalence relation in your problem, you can compute $\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$ for a bunch of integers and try to see what happens. So for the integers $\dots, -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots$, $\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$ is equal to $\dots, -3, -2,-2,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,2,2,\dots$. So you can see that the equivalence classes can be placed in bijection with the integers, and each equivalence class has (con't)

Comment: exactly two integers in it. So for instance, $[4]_R = [5]_R = \{4,5\} = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} | \lfloor n/2 \rfloor = \lfloor 4/2 \rfloor = 2\}$ --- this is the equivalence class that "corresponds to" the integer 2. The set of all equivalence classes is in bijection with the integers.

Comment: So instead of defining one large equivalence class I would need to define multiple smaller ones? Is there a way I can do one large equivalence class? Also thank you for spending so much time helping out with this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The point is that an equivalence relation breaks up a set into a bunch of equivalence classes (that you call "smaller" equivalence classes?). In a given equivalence class, every element is equivalent to every other element. It's a way of "gluing together" certain elements of the set --- in the example, pairs of integers get glued together so to speak. That's the best way I can explain it lol

Comment: @JaneDoé  The concept you want is a partition of the set.  I've tried to explain it in my answer below.

Comment: That's true, I just did not want to introduce yet another piece of terminology. But perhaps it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, any equivalence relation on a set is the same as a partition of the set.  Each element of the partition is an equivalence class.

The equivalence classes of this relation are sets of the form $\{2n, 2n+1\}$ for some $n \in \Bbb Z$.  Note that every integer is in exactly one of these sets -- that's how you know the collection of these sets is a partition.

You also could define this same equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$, in which case the equivalence classes would be sets of the form $[2n, 2n+2)$ for $n \in \Bbb Z$.  Again, note that every real number is in exactly one of these half-open intervals, which tells you that the set of these intervals is a partition, and therefore defines an equivalence relation.

Comment: So what you are saying is that when @Jane Doe gave the following example  $[4]_R = [5]_R = \{4,5\} = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} | \lfloor n/2 \rfloor = \lfloor 4/2 \rfloor = 2\}$ That equivalence class could be defined as $ [2n,2n+2) for n∈Z$ and that definition works for all the other equivalence classes?

Comment: What I did gives you the general form for all equivalence classes.  The specific equivalence class that @JaneDoe used as an example is what you get if you use $n=2$.